# Get absolute paths to NuGet dependency libraries via MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

I'm attempting to write a custom target in a shared library that will allow me to pull in all of the NuGet dependencies of our project in order to run ILRepack for dependency hiding.

My main challenge is that the project is multi-targeted across net45, net46 and netstandard2.0. If that wasn't the case, it would be fairly straightforward to use one of the off-the-shelf ILRepack targets from NuGet directly.

What I'm attempting is, after the build has completed and our DLL is built, to manually enumerate the dependent DLL paths, copy them into a known location, and then run ILRepack on our DLL to merge in all dependencies. I want to accomplish this via MSBuild to avoid having to write a complicated script that can retrieve dependencies for multiple targeted frameworks.

I've been focusing my investigation via a full project xml export created by running `dotnet msbuild /pp:fullproj.xml`. Is there a target or output parameter available as part of the build process that will let me pull in the absolute paths of all `.dll` files that would normally end up in the final `.nupkg`?

TL;DR Is there a built in way for me to enumerate the absolute paths of all NuGet dependency DLLs in an MSBuild target?

Answer (score 0):

You can try msbuild task from [ILRepack.Lib.MSBuild.Task](https://github.com/ravibpatel/ILRepack.Lib.MSBuild.Task).
This task lets you define a file named ILRepack.targets which contains required target and allows to customize the build process.
This helped me in similar case.

Comment: I did attempt to use a couple of the ILRepack tasks available on NuGet, but it seems that the paths to dependencies are only available during a net45 or net46 build - when the netatandard2.0 target runs, no file paths to the dependent DLLs are available.